# How to assign different functions to a variable in order to use different functions depending on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to assign different functions on a variable.
So the code is like:

```
import pandas as pd

def read_to_pandas(filename):
    extension=filename[filename.rfind('.')+1:]
    if ext ='xlsx':
        func = pd.read_excel()
    if ext=='csv':
        func = pd.read_csv()

    return func(path)

df = func('D:/Data/data.csv')
```

But it doesn't work.
How one can reassign variable-function?

Comment: Just remove the parentheses `()` at the end of `pd.read_excel()` and `pd.read_csv()`, you don't want to call the functions at this point.

Answer (score 1):

```
read_pd = {'csv':read_csv,'xlsx':read_excel}

extension=filename[filename.rfind('.')+1:]
if extension in read_pd: 
     read_pd[extension]()
```

Something like this can help you !!!

The read_csv should have `pd.read_csv` and read_excel should have `pd.read_excel`

As the question is more specific to assigning variable , Here below is the version of that:

```
def read_csv():
    print("Reading CSV")

def read_excel():
    print("Reading Excel")

filename = "sample.csv"
read_pd = {'csv':read_csv,'xlsx':read_excel}
func = None
extension=filename[filename.rfind('.')+1:]
print(extension)
if extension in read_pd: 
    func = read_pd[extension]

func()
```

Comment: Iterating on a dict to test if you have one of its keys defeats the purpose of the dict. Just do: `if extension in read_pd: read_pd[extension]()`

Comment: Yeah , Missed it , Updated the same. Thank you .

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but in my case I do some other extension-specific stuff, so I'm kinda limited to "if-then".

Comment: As question was more specific to assigning to a variable , I have modified the code a little bit to suit you , In that depending on the file format of the input we are just assigning it to a variable and then calling it will trigger the respective function.

Answer (score 0):

You to try

```
def read_to_pandas(filename):
    extension=filename[filename.rfind('.')+1:]
    if extension == 'xlsx':
        func = pd.read_excel
    if extension == 'csv':
        func = pd.read_csv

    return func

df = read_to_pandas('D:/Data/data.csv')
```